# Update value for flag column

Tags: sql

I want to create a stored procedure that updates the value for Current Flag to Y or N by comparing values of C1 and C2 and set the most recent one to Y and the older N. In the result set below, row 1 and 2 have the same values for C2 and C2, so I want to set current flag for the most recent as Y and for the older N. Row 3 in the below result set does not have duplicate so I want it to say Y.

```
10  12  9    1985-06-10     NULL
10  12  60   2015-09-10     NULL
3   5   23   2001-09-10     NULL
1   1   96   2010-09-10     NULL
1   1   71   2016-09-10     NULL
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in standard SQL using a correlated subquery:

```
update t
set flag = (
  case when date = (
    select max(date) 
    from t t2 
    where t2.c1 = t.c1 and t2.c2 = t.c1
  )
  then 'Y' else 'N'
  end
);
```

Specific databases might have alternative methods, but this should work in any database.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon, that did the job for me.